# how to create the subcolumns in the dataframe and add the data using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Actually, I am facing the problem to add the data in the subcolumn in the specific format. I have created the "Polypoints" as the main column and I want

```
df["Polypoints"] = [{"__type":"Polygon","coordinates":Row_list}]
```

where Row_list is the column of dataframe which contains the data in the below format

```
df["Row_list"] = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]
                 [x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]
                 [x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3]]
```

I want to convert the dataframe into json in the format 
"Polypoints" :{"__type":"Polygon" ,"coordinates":Row_list}

Comment: I have added the list in the Dataframe column "Row_list"

Comment: I have to add one more column "Polypoints" in the Dataframe  as specified above and add the data of Row_list column in the "coordinates" subcolumn.

Comment: Try the `json` or `jsonpickle` packages. E.g. `json.dumps(df)`.

Comment: Base on the question     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58091927/how-to-concatenate-pairs-of-row-elements-into-a-new-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe
I have issue related to the above answer. Please check the link and suggest for the issue

Comment: Did you try `json` like proposed in comment above? It sounds to me like a good option...

Comment: before json I have to create one column in the dataframe "Polypoint" specified in the above format

Comment: The DataFrame Column "Polypoints" once created in the specific format then it is easier to directly get the json file.

Comment: try `df['Polypoints'] = df.apply(lambda row: {"__type":"Polygon", "coordinates":row['Row_list']} ,axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks, Itamar your solution works for me

Comment: Also suggest for the question posted at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58112213/how-to-read-the-sublist-from-the-main-list-and-add-the-sublist-in-the-another-da

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do that.

One can create a function `create_polygon` that takes as input the dataframe (`df`), and the column name (`columname`). That would look like the following

```
def create_polygon(df, columnname):
    return {"__type":"Polygon", "coordinates":df[columnname]}
```

Considering that the column name will be `Row_list`, the following will already be enough

```
def create_polygon(df):
    return {"__type":"Polygon", "coordinates":df['Row_list']}
```

Then with [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) one can apply it to the column `Polypoints` as follows

```
df['Polypoints'] = df.apply(create_polygon, axis=1)
```

As Itamar Mushkin [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58109579/how-to-create-the-subcolumns-in-the-dataframe-and-add-the-data-using-pandas-in-p#comment102610898_58109579), one can also do it with a Lambda function as follows

```
df['Polypoints'] = df.apply(lambda row: {"__type":"Polygon", "coordinates":row['Row_list']} ,axis=1)
```